# Opposite of "catholic"

Tags: single-word-requests

So I looked up the actual definition of having a 'catholic taste', and it appears that I'd gathered the wrong contextual meaning for it.

> (especially of a person's tastes) including a wide variety of things; all-embracing.

I'd like to know the/a descriptor for having monogamous, boring, standard, reliable, consistent, never-varying, rigid, limited, what-you're-already-familiar-with, unadventurous, self-consistent, taste.

Obviously, I could use one of those words, but I'd liked the flavor of 'catholic'.  I'd also wanted a word which implied many/all of those things together (in varying degrees), without requiring a couple of sentences of explanation.

> He had catholic tastes in sandwiches.
>   He had catholic tastes in movies.
>   He had catholic tastes in girlfriends.

*Conservative*, *moderate*, and *conformist* as substitutes only work for some varieties of a-catholic tastes:

> He had an acatholic taste in girlfriends; namely blonde, blue-eyed, corn-fed wholesome Midwestern girls.

Doesn't work out so well, when you say:

> He had an acatholic taste in girlfriends; namely pierced, heavily tattooed, emo girls with radically dyed hair.

Which is not a standard, conservative, or moderate type of taste — but it is consistent, reliable, and unvarying (in this description). Getting the second guy a date with Sienna Miller would only work for someone with catholic tastes, not someone with a [blank] taste.

But, I'd like a go-to word, that I could use for both guys.

Or, example-wise: sandwiches. movies (scathing expose documentaries vs. summer blockblusters)

Comment: Can you give an example, a sentence where that word would fit?

Comment: How about *parochial*? Or *chauvinistic*?

Comment: You listed a good bunch of choices above.  Consulting a thesaurus might give you some more.

Comment: (And in the sense you're using it, "catholic" is not capitalized.)

Comment: I'm thinking the question title should be changed to "Opposite of 'catholic tastes'", since it seems like that's really what's being asked for, but I'm reluctant to make such a radical change to someone else's question.

Comment: How about "heretical?"

Comment: 'catholic taste' is not a common phrase.  Catholicism is a religion, it is not commonly attributed to a specific lifestyle in the USA

Comment: "Catholic", to a US Protestant of some denominations, is synonymous with "universal" (since versions of The Apostles' Creed and other liturgical items use the two words interchangeably).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to find an answer that has the same "flavor" as the word `catholic`, or one that pertains "especially to a person's tastes". It's just a pretty unique word.

In your place, I would just have to use "invariant" or "unvarying". Maybe "immutable". None of those are close to perfect, but they sort of get the meaning across without negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more insulting than you're looking for, but [**'narrow-minded'**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow-minded) might work:

> : not willing to accept opinions, beliefs, or behaviors that are unusual or different from your own

Answer (score -1):

Conformity

> behaviour in accordance with socially accepted conventions.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ['prescriptive'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescriptive)

> **adjective**
>
> 1 - Relating to the imposition or enforcement of a rule or method:
>    ‘these guidelines are not intended to be prescriptive’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*